# cocos2d-x ndk native build failed - cannot execute binary file

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have just created a new project with cocos2d-x 2.2.6 and ndk r9d and tried to build it and get the following error:

```
 $ /cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DSTest/proj.android/build_native.sh
NDK_ROOT = C:\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r9d
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DSTest/proj.android/../../..
APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DSTest/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DSTest/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
make: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DSTest/proj.android'
Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DSTest/proj.android/../../../cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= main.cpp
/bin/sh: /cygdrive/c/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/cygdrive/c/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-binary.mk:393: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/hellocpp/main.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/hellocpp/main.o] Error 126
make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/cocos2d-x/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/DSTest/proj.android'
```

I have had a search around for the above issue and have reinstalled ndk and cocos2d-x which has not resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to put all dependencies on c: drive, also use the latest cocos2dx version, because there's a lot of deprecated codes between cocos2dx 2..... and cocos2dx 3....

Comment: Everything is on the c drive. It did used to build but I am not sure what has changed, none of the cocos2dx 2 projects will build which is why I created a new test project to see if that was also the same. My long term plan is to move the projects to cocos2dx 3. But for the time being I am just trying to get the projects to build once again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just tried reinstalling NDK and cocos2d-x and it now works